# Selenium Automation - How to click on particular button periodically until getting another element's updated text value?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

In my webpage, I have a refresh button and one Text Field,
when i landed to that page, Initially that Text Field value would be `processing` (In backend there is a functionality which is processing, Inorder to inform the user, textfield value is processing in UI), and after functionality is done, that Text Field would be `completed`

Now coming to the question,
We will get to know the updated value of Text Field only when we click on the refresh button,

Is there a way to make a `WebElement` to be waited until that Text field has value as `completed`? We also need to click on that particular refresh button periodically to check that text field value became `completed` or not

I've found a method called `textToBePresentInElement` in `ExpectedConditions`, But using this, we cannot refresh button periodically,
Any other solution `selenium` webdriver is providing?

Comment: `ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement` should do the job if used correctly. Can you share URL so I can try it?

Comment: It is not a public webpage though, `textToBePresentInElement` is to check if text is preset or not but along with that i need a option to click some particular button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to implement a custom Expected condition:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition

public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> textToBePresentForElementWithRefreshByClick(By originalElement, Strint expectedText, By refreshElement) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        private boolean hasText = false;
        private String currentText = "";

        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            currentText = driver.findElement(originalElement).getText();
            hasText = currentText == expectedText;
            if(!hasText) {
                driver.findElement(refreshElement).click();
                // Optionally some sleep might be added here, like Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            return hasText;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("element \"%s\" should have text \"%s\", found text: \"%s\"", originalElement.toString(), expectedText, currentText);
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
By originalElement = ...;
By refreshElement = ...;

new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(
    textToBePresentForElementWithRefreshByClick(originalElement, "completed", refreshElement)
)
```

Comment: This approach is also looks fine

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a custom method to wait for sometime then to perform click operation. You can see below sample code,

**Code**:

*Create a re-usable method and write down the logic inside the method for click operation and element value check on given explicit interval times.*

```
public static void clickUntilStatusIsChanged(By element1, By element2, String expectedStatus, int timeOutSeconds) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

    /* The purpose of this loop is to wait for maximum of 50 seconds */
    for (int i = 0; i < timeOutSeconds / 10; i++) {
        if (wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(element2, expectedStatus))) {
            break;
        } else {
            /* Waits for 10 seconds and performs click operation */
            waitForTime(timeOutSeconds / 5);
            driver.findElement(element1).click();
        }
    }
}

public static void waitForTime(int interval) {
    int waitTillSeconds = interval;
    long waitTillTime = Instant.now().getEpochSecond() + waitTillSeconds;
    while (Instant.now().getEpochSecond() < waitTillTime) {
        // Do nothing...
    }
}
```

*Pass the parameters to the re-usable method*:

```
clickUntilStatusIsChanged(By.xpath("Element#1"), By.xpath("Element#2"), "completed", 50);
```

Comment: I did likely this already (I was searching some Utility methods in selenium to handle this scenario), Instead of `waitForTime()` method, I put `Thread.Sleep(15)`, Do you know which is preferrable?

Comment: upvoted! I will select Max answer as a verified one as i required this to be fixed using selenium utils. Thanks @Nandan for your answer